# SharePoint List is giving error message "Unable to render data"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint list filtered by "key Filters", when I change the value in "Dashboard" view, and click on "Stop editing", it is giving me an error message below

Unable to render data. if the problem persists, contact your system administrator.  
 
 Correlation ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

It was working till last one hour, I was trying to create different views.

Comment: This is a generic error, you need to turn off customErrors in the web.config.
Or see EventViewer to find the actual error

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a connection to your database for "AUTORITE NT\IUSR"

First time I had this error it saved me.

But now, i'm facing this issue again and can't find a solution. So if you find another one, let us know ;)

Edit: Incredible... I just set CustomError to "Off" instead of "RemoteOnly", had same error. After Reboot server it starts working..

Just do an iisreset and try again